# Произношение слова "фольклор"

Tags: орфоэпия

Как произносится слово "фольклор", с мягкой "л" или твёрдой? В школе учили, что пишем "о", читаем как "ё", а на Грамоте.ру вариант с мягким произношением даже не упоминается

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Т.Иванова, Т.Черкасова в справочнике " Русская речь" в эфире дают только твёрдое произношение, другие справочники говорят, что норма - твёрдое Л, но допустимо и устаревающее мягкое, в Викисловаре варианты равноправны. Вот здесь правильное произношение:
http://ru.forvo.com/word/%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%80/ - тоже по-разному. Так что как хотите, так и произносите.

Answer (score 1):

Вряд ли в школе могли такому учить. Разве что на уроках немецкого.
Аванесов дает [ль] как допустимый вариант. 
Я произношу [ль], но не стал бы рекомендовать этот вариант как основной. Мне просто трудно перестроить язык после первого мягкого Л.

Comment: Я, кстати, тоже произношу через второе мягкое [ль]
И причем тут немецкий, если википедия говорит, что слово английское (folklore)?

Comment: Википедия - тот еще источник. ))) 
Но дело не в этом. Английский я назвать не мог, там оба Л были бы твердыми. )))